# Contact Form 7 - Multiple text fields on the same line

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7, form-layout

I am using Contact Form 7 to design a booking form for a hotel.

http://istanabalian.com/book/

I can't figure out how to customize the layout. I'd like some of the text fields to be displayed on the same line but I don't find the correct identification for the elements and/or which CSS styling to use to achieve this very simple goal.

Here is the code :

```html
<div id="responsive-form" class="clearfix">

<label> Your Name (required)
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Your Email (required)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Arrival date
[date date-79 id:Arrivaldate date-format:mm/dd/yy] </label>

<label> Departure date
[date date-80 id:Departuredate date-format:mm/dd/yy] </label>

<label> How many guests?
    [text your-guests] </label>

<div class="form-row">
       <p>Number of adults [text your-adults]</p>
       <p>Number of children under 6 years old [text your-little-children]</p>
       <p>Number of children under 12 years old [text your-big-children]</p>
</div>

Select your preferred accomodation
    [checkbox your-accomodation use_label_element "Wayan (Two-story villa)" "Kadek (Two-story villa)" "Nyoman (Garden bungalow)" "Kehut (Garden bungalow)" "Pasca (Garden bungalow)"]

Do you need transportation to the hotel ? 
[radio your-pickup default:1 use_label_element exclusive "No transport needed" "Transport from Denpasar airport" "Transsport from Gilimanuk Ferry"]

<label> Do you want us to arrange motorbike rental for you ? 
    [text your-motorbikes] </label>

<label> Tell us more about what brings you to Balian
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[submit "Send"]

</div>
```

I want to display the p elements of the form-row elements on a single line. I have tried this CSS line :

```html
.form_row p{
display: inline-block
}
```

But it does not do anything. I feel I am missing something, can anybody help ?

Many thanks in advance,

Benjamin

Comment: This might help http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-style-contact-form-7-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably have a CSS rule that makes the `<p>` element full-width.

Why not use `<div>` and use the theme's classes?

```
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="grid-33">Number of adults [text your-adults]</div>
   <div class="grid-33">Number of children under 6 years old [text your-little-children]</div >
   <div class="grid-33">Number of children under 12 years old [text your-big-children]</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, as you said I have probably a rule which makes <p> but also <span> elements full-width.

I took over the work of somebody who used a template I have no experience with, thus it is difficult for me to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Add a new line to the css `width:33%;` that should solve the issue

Comment: Actually I am unable to style anything of this form, another rule is overtaking.

Comment: Ok, let's change the element type to a div then. I'll update my answer

Comment: Aha, your CSS rule isn't even reflecting on the front end. I've updated my snippet to use your theme's classes and this should fix it

Comment: Awesome! Your theme uses classes to create a responsive layout. The concept is that you have many rows and within each row there are columns or grids. The class name must have "grid-30" if it is 30% width or "grid-75" if 75% etc. So if you have an item, preferably a `div` you apply that class and it will become the width you define. If it doesn't work as expected, it may be within another `div` that has its own rule: div1 is `grid-50` and div2 is inside div1, div2 is `grid-33`; you may expect div2 to be 1/3 (33%) of the screen but it will only be 1/6 (1/3 of 1/2 - div1's width). Good luck

Comment: Can I suggest you change your input fields to numbers (on this area or where numbers are expected) or a select (drop down)? You will find down the line that someone can enter any text in that area which may require the hotel staff to clarify with the person trying to book: https://contactform7.com/number-fields/

Comment: Very good suggestion !!

Thank you for everything. 

Can I get rid of the small shift in the multi-elements line ? There is a small offset before and after the first and last elements.

Answer (score 5):

**You can simply use HTML table structure!!!**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">[text* Name placeholder "Your Name"]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>[text* Class placeholder "Enter Class"]
    </td>
    <td>
      [text* Medium placeholder "Enter Medium"]
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
[submit "Submit"]
```

Comment: Thanks that was easy!

Answer (score 3):

You can use your theme grid to make it in two column. see below snippet

```html
<div id="responsive-form" class="clearfix">
<div class="vc_row ">
  <div class="vc_col-sm-6">
    <label> Your Name (required)
        [text* your-name] </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="vc_col-sm-6">
    <label> Your Email (required)
        [email* your-email] </label>
  </div>
</div>
<label> Arrival date
[date date-79 id:Arrivaldate date-format:mm/dd/yy] </label>

<label> Departure date
[date date-80 id:Departuredate date-format:mm/dd/yy] </label>

<label> How many guests?
    [text your-guests] </label>

<div class="form-row">
       <p>Number of adults [text your-adults]</p>
       <p>Number of children under 6 years old [text your-little-children]</p>
       <p>Number of children under 12 years old [text your-big-children]</p>
</div>

Select your preferred accomodation
    [checkbox your-accomodation use_label_element "Wayan (Two-story villa)" "Kadek (Two-story villa)" "Nyoman (Garden bungalow)" "Kehut (Garden bungalow)" "Pasca (Garden bungalow)"]

Do you need transportation to the hotel ? 
[radio your-pickup default:1 use_label_element exclusive "No transport needed" "Transport from Denpasar airport" "Transsport from Gilimanuk Ferry"]

<label> Do you want us to arrange motorbike rental for you ? 
    [text your-motorbikes] </label>

<label> Tell us more about what brings you to Balian
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[submit "Send"]

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an HTML table as follows :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Number of adults [text your-adults]</td>
        <td>Number of children under 6 years old [text your-little-children]</td>
        <td>Number of children under 12 years old [text your-big-children]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been quite frustrated with the lack of design solutions for Contact Form 7.
A year ago, I was tasked with creating multiple forms in cf7, with complex layout requirements.   To solve this problem I set about creating a plugin that allows for responsive grid-layout designs as well as the ability to have a modular approach to form building, ie being able to reuse existing forms into larger form constructs.
I just released the [Smart Grid-layout design for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/), it gives a grid UI editor in the dashboard that allows you to build a 3 columns layout in a single row.  You don't need to mess around with css, the layout will be rendered on your page.  It is also responsive, to it will default to 3 rows on a mobile phone.

Give it a try and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working well for me,  you just have a syntax error in your CSS. The name of your element in the HTML is `form-row` but in CSS  you have written `form_row`. I just changed the CSS selector to `form-row` and everything works as expected.

```css
.form-row p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hope this video instruction will help you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahGn9zcgj3A)

Here is the CSS code for my contact form 7:

```
/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

#knopka
{
    color: #fffff;
    background: #8F8CA0;
    width: 90%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}﻿
```